# Script only working when the script is restarted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets-api

```
with open("a.txt", "r") as a:
    try:     
        b = a.readlines()[2]
        wks = gc.open('Test').sheet1
        if b not in open('c.txt').read():
            check = "True"
            wks.append_row(['test', 'test'])
            print("Spreadsheet appended.")
            with open("c.txt", "a") as c:
                c.write(blah_blah+"\n")
        else:
            check = "False"
            do_x()
    except:
        pass
```

Currently, the spreadsheet is only appended if the script is restarted. I'd like to have the script append to the spreadsheet automatically but I'm not sure where the error is!

Edit: Removing the try/except returned this error after checking back 12 hours or so.

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
 "error": {
 "errors": [
  {
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "authError",
   "message": "Invalid Credentials",
   "locationType": "header",
   "location": "Authorization"
  }
 ],
 "code": 401,
 "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Comment: Please remove `try/except`. It is masking the errors instead of revealing and solving them.

Comment: I don't understand what's the wanted behavior. Do you want to continuously read from file and append?

Comment: @DYZ It seems removing the try/except isn't returning the same issue anymore.. Very confusing as to why that may be? I should also point out that the try/except is somewhat necessary in case of api failure although it seems to be causing my issue...

Comment: @RoyM the `if b not in open('c.txt').read():` previously failed/was skipped when it shouldn't be before I removed the try/except block

Comment: For starters, handle your file access properly which includes closing a file handle before you attempt to open it again. `open('c.txt').read()` does not guarantee a file handle close before you're attempting to open it for appending...

Comment: Your try/except must target specific types if errors in specific lines and at least report them. Having one blanket and silent try/except is pointless.

Comment: `gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
`

Comment: @DYZ see edits.

Comment: So, now you know what went wrong: invalid credentials. You may have been chocked dir making too many requests.

Comment: @DYZ after searching the error, I'm inclined to believe the credentials expire after x hours. The script only entered the credentials at startup, I've adjusted it to enter in every 3200 seconds now, I'll keep the post updated!